# Spring 3 MVC on JBoss 5.1: ConflictingBeanDefinitionException

Tags: exception, spring-mvc, jboss

When I try to deploy my application on JBoss 5.1 Spring 3 MVC throw me this stack trace: http://pastebin.com/Aah386PJ

Telling me that I have two definition of the same bean in two different packages. The thing is I don't have this IntershipConfigurationController in the controller package, but I have it in controller.internshipConfiguration. I previously add it under the root of controller but I deleted it from SVN and it doesn't appear anymore in the tree.

I cleaned JBoss, Eclipse's project, tried to redeploy it, to restart JBoss, Eclipse, etc. but I can't get this project working while my mates with the same repository can run it with no issue.

I don't know what to do this is really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally deleted my JBoss folder, removed the projects from JBoss in Eclipse, extract a proper JBoss, made a clean on JBoss in Eclipse and then redeployed my projects and it's now working.

Nonetheless it's a really strange issue...

Edit :
It was in fact because the build folder at the root of my project was versioned and the old classes were still present.
Now the folder is ignored and removed from the SVN and I've deleted the old classes from my FS.

Answer (score 0):

I know this can be frustrating sometimes but you might want to know why this could happen. Spring annotation based ant path matcher checks for the class-path with a URI pattern to search for controllers or components. In your case the class-path either has a jar having the previous version of your class or some referencing .class file in your build path.

> Make sure you have your project cleaned up and if possible disconnect
>   from SVN and download the project again.
>
> You could also try CTRL+SHIFT+T to see if your controller is
>   referenced from any other library.